# Geting TypeError: index.saveObject is not a function for algolia search

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, algolia

```
    const searchClient: any = algoliasearch(
    '',   //Application ID
    '' //API Key
  );

    const index: any = searchClient.initIndex('hackernews_search');

  const [newsData, setNewsData] = useState<News[]>([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
        const getCurrentPageData = async () => {
          let currentNewsData : News[] = [];
            const response = await axios.get(`https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story&hitsPerPage=30&page=${currentPage}`)
                    response.data.hits.map((result:any) => {
                        let newsObject :News = {
                            title: result.title,
                            url: result.url,
                            points: result.points,
                        }
                        currentNewsData.push(newsObject)
                    })
            setNewsData(currentNewsData);
            index.saveObjects(currentNewsData);
          }
        getCurrentPageData();
    },[currentPage])
```

I am fetching the data from an api and then saving it in algolia in order to use the Instant Search Component provided by algolia.
For the above code, I am getting this error.

> TypeError: index.saveObject is not a function
> at getCurrentPageData (Home.tsx:37:1)

I am not sure what is going wrong, as this is the method followed in the docs - https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/save-objects/#examples.
Any suggestion would be appreciated

**I was able to solve this error, it was simple import error**

**Solution**

I was getting this error as I had imported algoliasearch from the algoliasearch/lite package which only provides search methods, that is why I was getting an error when using the saveObjects method as it was a write method. Importing the entire package i.e. `import algoliasearch from algoliasearch` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you log `index` before that `saveObjects` call, is it uninitialized or can you see the methods in the console? This may help you track down what exactly the `index` variable is and why that method doesn't exist.

```js
console.log(index)
```

One thing to keep in mind if you want to save objects, you'll need a write key. I only mention this because it looks like you are using React and your write keys would be exposed in your application if anyone did some digging. If it's a non-public app it should be okay but just wanted to bring this up.

Also, if you are just looking to browse that Index, you could always use it directly using the public credentials:

```
App Id: UJ5WYC0L7X
API Key: 8ece23f8eb07cd25d40262a1764599b1
Index Name: Item_production
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I was able to solve this error, it was because of importing the wrong package. I have posted the solution above with the question